# How to remap an existing keybinding in Zathura

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zathura

After reading the `man zathurarc` for the map command, I still don't know how to remap an existing keybinding. By "remapping", I mean replacing a current keymapping for a given action.

#### Problem:

`<C-Button1>` (Control + click) is currently mapped to the [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118491/95423) backward search, with the following settings in my `zathurarc` config file:

```
set dbus-service true # Already the default
set synctex true      # Already the default
set synctex-editor-command "gvim --servername GVIMTEX --remote +%{line} %{input}"
```

However, I don't like using the mouse, so I want to map the synctex action to, say `<C-s>`.

#### Trials

I tried the following line in my zathurarc:

```
map <C-s> feedkeys "<C-Button1>"
```

It doesn't work and shows "`open n1>`" in the inputbar.

#### Alternative ideas

I could also map `<C-s>` to the shortcut_function for synctex, if only I knew what it was...

#### Complains

I find that there is too few information in the zathura documentation.
For example I would like to know:

1. how to list *all* current key bindings (that would help not to override current mappings...)
2. how to use the `feedkeys` function, because it is nowhere in my documentation, and I don't know from which version it was available (I have Ubuntu 16.04 and zathura 0.3.5).
3. what is the shortcut_function used for synctex. Is there one?

Could anyone show me how to use `<C-s>` instead of `<C-Button1>`?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but using xdotool to do the ctrl click did the job for me. I wrote this short bash script (also found here [zathura_backward_search.sh](https://gist.github.com/halvarsu/eebf4559ebb0a91817cd2a063e497b9c)):

```
#!/bin/bash

ACTIVEWINDOW=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
eval $(xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $ACTIVEWINDOW)

HALF_WIDTH="$(($WIDTH / 2 + 10))"
HALF_HEIGHT="$(($HEIGHT / 2))"

xdotool mousemove --window $ACTIVEWINDOW $HALF_WIDTH $HALF_HEIGHT keydown ctrl click 1 keyup ctrl
```

Place this on your path, `chmod +x` it, and execute it in zathura using `:exec zathura_backward_search.sh`. Alternatively you can map `<C-s>` to this script using `map <C-s> exec ctrl_click_center_window.sh` in your `zathurarc`. It is a bit slow (and could probably be made faster), but works nonetheless.